# jsonnet: How to serialize array into string

Tags: jsonnet

How to convert this
["a", "b", "c", "d"]

into

"a", "b", "c", "d"

in JSONNET (https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html)

Answer (score 2):

There exists an `std.toString` function, which might do want you want. For example `std.toString(["a", "b", "c", "d"])` results in a string `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. It is slightly different from your example output `"a", "b", "c", "d"`.

If you want to have exactly the format that you want, you can of course build the string yourself. The most obvious way is writing a recursive function (that's how you iterate in Jsonnet):

```
local arrayToString(arr) =
  local aux(arr, index) =
    // Assuming escapeStringJson is how you want to serialize
    // the elements. Of course you can use any other way
    // to serialize them (e.g. toString or manifestJson).
    local elem = std.escapeStringJson(arr[index]);
    if index == std.length(arr) - 1 then
      elem
    else
      elem + ", " + aux(arr, index + 1)
  ;
  aux(arr, 0);
arrayToString(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

A more idiomatic way would be to use map to transform all elements of the array and then join to merge them into one string:

```
local arrayToString(arr) = std.join(", ", std.map(std.escapeStringJson, arr));
arrayToString(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```